# GroupDel Samba Share doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, samba, users, 20.10, samba4

i tried deleting sambashare group with the following command groupdel sambashare

and i later got  Permission denied and cannot lock /etc/group; try again later can someone help me?

Comment: The command would need to be run as root (using `sudo` for example) - did you do so?

Comment: i run as root by using sudo again, got sudo and still got permission denied

Comment: excuse me, but is there a way to lsit all users in samba share and remove them with terminal?

Comment: it's crucial that you share with us your input and output commands

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you may still have at least one user account associated with the group. From [the "Caveats" section of the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/groupdel.8.html):

```
You may not remove the primary group of any existing user. You must remove the user
before you remove the group.

You should manually check all file systems to ensure that no files remain owned by
this group.
```

With this in mind, you can see which users are associated with the `sambashare` group in Terminal like this:

```
getent group sambashare
```

This may give you something like this:

```
sambashare:x:1001:samba,alec
```

<sup>**Note:** In this example, `sambashare` is the group name, `1001` is the `gid` (group ID) value, and `samba,alec` are the user accounts associated with the group.</sup>

You can remove the user accounts from the group like this:

```
sudo deluser {username} sambashare
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{username}` with the actual user name that you are removing from the group. While `deluser` may infer you are deleting a user account, it will simply remove a user account from a group.</sup>

If the user is *only* part of `sambashare`, then you will probably want to remove the user completely:

```
sudo deluser {username}
```

<sup>**Note:** If the user account has a home directory and you would like it removed at the same time, you can add `--remove-home` between `deluser` and the `{username}`.</sup>

Once the group has no accounts associated with it, you can remove the group completely:

```
sudo groupdel sambashare
```

<sup>**Note:** *Technically* you can run this so long as no user account has `sambashare` as their primary group, but you may want to remove all accounts first, just to be safe.</sup>

This should do what you are hoping to accomplish